# Jquery validate - removing a generated label

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm adding a password strength function to my existing validate settings and I'm down to one last item that I'm not sure how best to accomplish.  My error display looks like this:

```
highlight: function(label) {
   $(label).closest('.form-element').addClass('error').closest('.form-element').removeClass('success');
   $('#result').html('');/*removes any strength messages on failed validation*/
        },
success: function(label) {
        label
        .text('OK!').addClass('valid')
        .closest('.form-element').addClass('success');
        },
```

the id "result" is the password strength message.  So when a validation error (range length, required) etc. is triggered any message regarding the strength of the password is hidden.

The relevant portion password strength check is this:

```
if (strength < 2 ){
        $('#result').removeClass();
        $('#result').addClass('passwordWeak');
    return '(Password is weak)'
} else if (strength == 2) {
    $('#result').removeClass();
    $('#result').addClass('passwordGood');
    return '(Password is good)'
} else {
    $('#result').removeClass();
    $('#result').addClass('passwordStrong');
    return '(Password is strong)'
}
};
```

What I'd like to have happen is if any of the validate errors are shown, don't show one of these errors.  They way I'm triggering it is enter 3 characters (shows "password is weak"), tab to next field (which fires the validate error on minimum length not 6 and hides "password is weak"), and then go back to add more characters to the password I still have the validate error message but as soon as I key up on character 4 I get the "password is weak".  I only one those ratings to show if no errors from validate are currently showing.

The generated error label for validate looks like this:

```
<label class="error" for="thispassword" generated="true">Password must be between 6 and 50 characters.</label>
```

Comment: can you use hasClass() to determine it. something like **if (!$(label).closest('.form-element').hasClass('error') && strength < 2 )** , which means to execute the if block the element should not contain .error class

Comment: That gives a "label is not defined" because the label that has the class 'error' isn't in existence before the validation error is thrown, so the initial password strength test failes.

Comment: can u post some jsfiddle relevant to your code...

Comment: Sorry - had to hop the train.  Here's the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/sJ6Hg/3/   if you type 3 characters in the password box, you'll get weak password, hit tab and you'll get validate fail (and weak password vanishes as expected).  then add a 4th character - now you have both messages.  I'm hoping to only show the password strength message if the validate error doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved it (for now).  In my keyup() on the password field I added two lines - one to hide the generated error label (generated by validate) and the other to remove the error class on the actual input field:

```
$('#thispassword').keyup(function () {
    //$('label.error').hide();
    // prev hids all error labels following just gets the one we want
    $('#result').prev('label.error').hide();
    $(this).closest('.form-element').removeClass('error');
    $('#result').html(checkStrength($('#thispassword').val()));
});
```